# I'm able to connect to MQTT broker running in a container with any client certificate

Tags: docker, ssl, mqtt, tls1.2, mosquitto

I have created an MQTT broker (Env : Docker Container , baseimage : Ubuntu:18) with self signed certificates with commonname set to localhost.

but i m able to connect to MQTT broker with any client certificate. How do i stop this.

Here is the mosquitto configuration :

````
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example

pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
cafile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.key
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.crt
require_certificate false
password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd```
````

Comment: What do you think `require_certificate false` means?

Comment: When I made it to true : getting this error : error:1417C0C7:SSL routines:tls_process_client_certificate:peer did not return a certificate.  , Inspite of passing the certificate.

Comment: Followed the instructions mentioned n this : http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mosquitto-tls/.             Only change made was comman name is set to localhost

Answer (score 1):

If you want to force clients to supply a certificate then you need to have

`require_certificate true`

Client certificates will need to be signed by a CA that is in `cafile` or `capth` to be accepted.

Since the certificate will be used to assert the user's identity the `passwd_file` will not be used. If you want to use the ACL (with the `acl_file` to control what topics a given user can use you will need to add `use_identity_as_username true` or `use_subject_as_username true` to set which item in the certificate to be the username.

From the [man page](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html):

> When using certificate based encryption there are three options that
> affect authentication. The first is require_certificate, which may be
> set to true or false. If false, the SSL/TLS component of the client
> will verify the server but there is no requirement for the client to
> provide anything for the server: authentication is limited to the MQTT
> built in username/password. If require_certificate is true, the client
> must provide a valid certificate in order to connect successfully. In
> this case, the second and third options, use_identity_as_username and
> use_subject_as_username, become relevant. If set to true,
> use_identity_as_username causes the Common Name (CN) from the client
> certificate to be used instead of the MQTT username for access control
> purposes. The password is not used because it is assumed that only
> authenticated clients have valid certificates. This means that any CA
> certificates you include in cafile or capath will be able to issue
> client certificates that are valid for connecting to your broker. If
> use_identity_as_username is false, the client must authenticate as
> normal (if required by password_file) through the MQTT options. The
> same principle applies for the use_subject_as_username option, but the
> entire certificate subject is used as the username instead of just the
> CN.

Comment: Sorry i m little new to MQTT, When i made  `require_certificate true`. and passed the client certificate, I m getting this error : `error:1417C0C7:SSL routines:tls_process_client_certificate:peer did not return a certificate`. its the same certificate which i have mentioned on configuration. `cafile`

Comment: Edit the question to show how you are configuring the client